# Thunderbird message sorting - wrong dates

Tags: imap, thunderbird

Thunderbird 3 is having a problem with one of my IMAP accounts.

When sorted by date, it displays 10-15 messages at the top (newest) when in fact they are very old message. (pre-2010, over a year old, some up to 6-7 years old)

It's not game-breaking, but it is annoying, as I have to look past those to check for "new" messages. Is there any way to fix this? I'd considered re-downloading all the messages via IMAP, but that would take weeks (>50,000 messages).

When I open it, it displays the *correct* date, also when I use "View Source" the **Date:** header has the correct date (2009, 2006, etc). Is there any way to make Thunderbird realize that it should be sorted down with the rest of the 2006/2009 messages?

*None of my other IMAP accounts (many with the same host server) have this issue.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sorting by "date" or by "received" ?

"Received" is known to have [some issues](http://www.emaildiscussions.com/showthread.php?t=59640) on IMAP, so sorting by date is recommended.

Comment: Is there something different about the problematic IMAP server ?

Comment: Try to find something that is different about this account. One thing you could try is to recreate another identical account and see if it shows the same symptoms (it might be that some obscure manipulation or TB3 bug caused this strange behavior for this one account).

Comment: There must be some difference in the message headers. Try to compare the headers for messages from 2 accounts from the same server : one where sorting works and one that doesn't. You could also post them in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. I do not have fix for this but maybe a workaround if you want to sort the messages correctly, just show the column 'Order received' and sort it using this column.

Answer (score 1):

In the current TB version (102.12.0 (64-Bit)) I suddenly had the same problem when installing a fresh TB and starting with a fresh profile.

After receiving all mails from my provider, both the **Date** and **Received** columns showed todays date for some mails I got 7 years ago.

What solved the problem for me was to set "mailnews.customDBHeaders" to "Received" in the advanced configuration.
Then I deleted the profile from within TB and recreated it. After receiving the mails again, everything seems to be fine.

I saw that the problematic mails did not have a **Date:** in their headers (in the source code) but merely **Received:** parts. I would expect TB toautomatically consider the last **Received:** date by default in this case. However, seems like manual intervention is necessary.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry bot, I only found this solution by trial and error finally following this [advice](https://www.thunderbird-mail.de/forum/thread/87768-bei-vielen-mails-wird-ein-falsches-datum-angezeigt/?postID=482761#post482761) in the German forums. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The wrong sort is caused by implemetation of email threads feature.
If you turn off the threads (View -> Sort By -> Unthreaded) everything will be sorted well, old fashioned as before.